# CocoaPods equivalent to Maven SNAPSHOT builds

Tags: cocoapods

Is there an equivalent concept in CocoaPods to SNAPSHOT builds in Maven?

I have a private podspec repo setup, and I'd like to publish a new development version after each CI run.  For my Android builds, I have an Artifactory server setup, where the CI publishes a SNAPSHOT build after each run (only keeping the most recent 5).  Is there an easy/recommended way of accomplishing this with Cocoapods?

Comment: Currently I am putting the output of the _pod install_ command in a txt file and save this to Artifactory. Obviously not a good solution, but for the moment it does its job of keeping track of the used library versions top-down. To check bottom-up which version is in which artifacts, this doesn't help... So I am also very interested in a solution of this!

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the [CocoaPods Versioning Specifics](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html#cocoapods-versioning-specifics) section of the [Making a CocoaPod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html) document, you'll see that this is supported. That document gives an example of specifying a pre-release version as `1.2-beta3`. However, if you look into the [Prerelease Gems](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#prerelease-gems) section of the RubyGems [Patterns](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/) document (which the [Making a CocoaPod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html) document links to), you'll see that the recommendation is to specify the pre-release version as `1.2.beta.3`. I'm sure both work but you can easily validate this by creating a podspec file and running the `pod spec lint MyPrivateLibrary.podspec` command against it. If the version name you've chosen is good, then you'll see a `"MyPrivateLibrary.podspec passed validation"` message when the lint command completes.